# WPF - Drawing 3D Object

Tags: wpf

I am newbie to WPF.
I have drawn simple 3D cube and rotate it with mouse 
But my question is,
**is it possible to draw wireframe object in WPF Without using any third party library(eg.Charles Petzold's libraty etc..)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatly the DirectX that WPF is built upon doesn't allow drawing lines, only rectangles which in turn means no wireframe. Sorry, you´ll have to look around for another solution.